# Typescript object and Promise typehints

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I'm trying to make a method like so:

```
emit(identifier: string, parameters: object = {}): Promise {
    return new Promise(...);
}
```

I have two issues:

- There is no `object` primitive on Typescript so I have to use `any`. Is there any way to typehint object (an object literal to be more precise) for the second parameter?
- How can I define function return type to be a Promise? The compiler complains about `Promise<T>` and I'm not really familiar with Java-like generics.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

There's no `object`, but you can use `Object`, but this is [what the docs say](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

> The any type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript,
>   allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type-checking during
>   compilation. You might expect Object to play a similar role, as it
>   does in other languages. But variables of type Object only allow you
>   to assign any value to them - you can’t call arbitrary methods on
>   them, even ones that actually exist

In your case you should be using `any`.

The `Promise` object uses generics in order to define what you're "promising", so if you'll return a promise to a number then it will be `Promise<number>`.
If the type that the promise returns varies then just return `Promise<any>`.